# Border for table th not working in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-table

I have datagrid table with some styles applied to it. Everything is working fine Chrome and Firefox but border is not applied to table thead th in IE. the borders are seen when I apply the same styles to table tbody td. In the following styles, border-left is not working in IE.

```
.datagrid table thead th {
color: #4180ab;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 30px;
text-align: center;
border-left: 1px solid #a8cbd1;
background: #f1f6fa;
}
```

//HTML Markup

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
<thead class="thead">
    <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Application Number</th>
        <th>Given Name</th>
        <th>Family Name</th>
        <th>Nationality</th>
        <th>Passport Number</th>
        <th>Visa Type</th>
        <th>Transaction Type</th>
        <th>Submission Date</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="gradeX">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>APP1212</td>
        <td>Steven</td>
        <td class="center">Gerrard</td>
        <td class="center">British</td>
        <td>12121212</td>
        <td>Tourist Visa</td>
        <td>454584545</td>
        <td>20-01-2014<img src="images/lock.png" alt="" class="lock"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gradeC">
        <td>2</td>
        <td>APP1012</td>
        <td>Fernando</td>
        <td class="center">Torres</td>
        <td class="center">Spanish</td>
        <td>12121212</td>
        <td>Short Work Visa</td>
        <td>454584545</td>
        <td>20-01-2014<img src="images/lock.png" alt="" class="lock"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gradeA">
        <td>3</td>
        <td>APP1512</td>
        <td>Xabi</td>
        <td class="center">Alonso</td>
        <td class="center">Spanish</td>
        <td>12121212</td>
        <td>Tourist Visa</td>
        <td>454584545</td>
        <td>20-01-2014<img src="images/lock.png" alt="" class="lock"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gradeA">
        <td>4</td>
        <td>APP1282</td>
        <td>Zlatan</td>
        <td class="center">Ibrahimovic</td>
        <td class="center">Swedish</td>
        <td>12121212</td>
        <td>Short Work Visa</td>
        <td>454584545</td>
        <td>20-01-2014<img src="images/lock.png" alt="" class="lock"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gradeA">
        <td>5</td>
        <td>APP1612</td>
        <td>Robin</td>
        <td class="center">Van Persie</td>
        <td class="center">Dutch</td>
        <td>12121212</td>
        <td>Tourist Visa</td>
        <td>454584545</td>
        <td>20-01-2014<img src="images/lock.png" alt="" class="lock"></td>
    </tr>

            <tr class="gradeX">
        <td>6</td>
        <td>APP1212</td>
        <td>Steven</td>
        <td class="center">Gerrard</td>
        <td class="center">British</td>
        <td>12121212</td>
        <td>Tourist Visa</td>
        <td>454584545</td>
        <td>20-01-2014<img src="images/lock.png" alt="" class="lock"></td>
    </tr>

</tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Can you share you HTML so we know how your table is structured?

Comment: Which version of IE? The first thing that comes to mind is it may be picky about `.datagrid table thead th` vs. `.datagrid table thead tr th`

Comment: Using [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zLn4J/), the `border-left` rule is working fine for me in IE11. Note that I removed the `.datagrid` portion of your CSS selector since your markup doesn't include anything matching that.

Comment: Just found out that the borders appear in IE until i click "Allow Blocked Content" prompt when i open the page. but once i click on that, it disappears.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution I've seen to this problem is applying

```
background-clip: padding-box;
```

to the th elements.

IE seems to render the background over the borders in some situations without this.

Answer (score 2):

Try to apply

```
border-collapse: separate;
```

to the related table

Comment: @dvln could you please accept the answer as a solution if you find this helpful and it solved your problem? Thanks!

Comment: This can have additional styling consequences, causing additional perhaps undesired separation between cells.

Comment: @stealthwang yes, agree, it can